# bindy csv encoding different from local

Tags: apache-camel, bindy

Where can I define the encoding of my input file in order to be correctly read by Bindy ?
My input file is ISO-8859-1, CRLF
My local is UTF-8 (I don't to change it...)

So when I read my file some character are wrong...

camel:

```
.process(debugProcessor)
        .unmarshal().bindy(BindyType.Csv, "mypackage.com")
```

Bindy:

```
@CsvRecord(separator = "\u0009", skipFirstLine = true)
public class elModel extends elModelGeneric{

/** Général */

@DataField(pos = 1)
/* N° id. */ String id;
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the encoding when reading your source. If your source is a file, this is defined as follows:

```
from("file:inbox?charset=ISO-8859-1")
    .process(debugProcessor)
    .unmarshal().bindy(BindyType.Csv, "mypackage.com")
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks this work fine to read the file. I'm actually having some trouble with Bindy :
    from("file:inbox?charset=ISO-8859-1")
    .process(debugProcessor)
    .unmarshal().bindy(BindyType.Csv, "mypackage.com")

Answer (score 0):

Thanks this work fine to read correctly the file. 
I'm actually having some trouble with Bindy :
This as a test sample doesn't work :

```
from("file:inbox?charset=ISO-8859-1")
.process(debugProcessor)
.unmarshal().bindy(BindyType.Csv, "mypackage.com")
.marshal().bindy(BindyType.Csv, "mypackage.com")
.to("file:output/test.csv?charset=UTF-8");
```

The output encoding is wrong (it contains some "?" characters for "é" input char)
Could it be related to the Locale needed for Bindy to be set ?
I made several tests but couldn't get the right output.

Comment: The file:inbox?charset=ISO-8859-1 route adds a CamelCharsetName header that will be used by bindy. Either try using UTF-8 instead or remove that header.